# Windows could not start the SQL Sever(SQLExpress) service on local Computer

Tags: visual-studio-2015

> Error 14001: The application has failed to start because its side by
>   side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log
>   or use the command-line `sxstrace.exe` tool for more details.

I have installed Visual Studio 2015.

Is there any problem in my Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you use sxstrace.exe?

Comment: No. I dont know how to use sxstrace.exe, How to solve my problem using even log or sxstrace.exe tool ? can you help me please ?

Comment: Try searching the internet :-) http://codeketchup.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-correct-side-by-side.html

Comment: This was the error on event log, :-
 
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.ATL,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.1833" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: processorArchitecture="amd64" this was the problem i think, My processor is intel